# Using decoded data from an API into an algorithm

Tags: swift, algorithm, api

I successfully fetched and decoded data from an API and now have access to all the data I need to be used in the algorithm I want to write in my App.

The issue is that I don't know how to access this data after I decoded it, I can print it immediately after it's decoded but I have no idea how to use it in another function or place in my app.

Here is my Playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

enum MyError : Error {
    case FoundNil(String)
}

struct Level: Codable {
    let time: Double
    let close: Double
    let high: Double
    let low: Double
    let open: Double
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let data: [Level]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "Data"
    }
}

func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Response?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            if let marketData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                print(marketData.data[0].open)
                print(marketData.data[1].open)
                print("Average=", (marketData.data[0].open + marketData.data[1].open) / 2)
                //completion(marketData, nil)
                throw MyError.FoundNil("data")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

fetchData() { items, error in
    guard let items = items,
        error == nil else {
            print(error ?? "Unknown error")
            return
    }
    print(items)
}
```

How can I use .data[0], .data[1], ..., somewhere else?

Comment: Can you please define somewhere else?

Comment: As in another file or function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what is your real issue, because you have written everything you need here, but as far I understand , to pass data

just uncomment this line `completion(marketData, nil)`

and in

```
fetchData() { items, error in
    guard let items = items,
        error == nil else {
            print(error ?? "Unknown error")
            return
    }
    print(items)
}
```

`items` is an object of your `struct Response`. You can pass this anywhere in your other `class` , by just creating an another variable like:

```
var items : Response!
```

for example :

```
 class SomeOtherClass : NSObject{
    var items : Response!
func printSomeData()
{
 print(items.data[0].open)
 print(items.data[1].open)
 print("Average=", (items.data[0].open + items.data[1].open) / 2)
}
    }
```

and in `fetchData` method write this:

```
 fetchData() { items, error in
            guard let items = items,
                error == nil else {
                    print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                    return
            }
            let otherObject = SomeOtherClass()
    otherObject.items = items
otherObject.printSomeData()
        }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot Arun!

Comment: Happy to help. : )

Answer (score 2):

You data will be available in your `fecthData()` call. Probably what you want is your `items` variable, where you're printing it. But make sure to call the completion in your `fetchData` implementation.

**WARNING: Untested code.**

```
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

enum MyError: Error {
    case FoundNil(String)
    case DecodingData(Data)
}

struct Level: Codable {
    let time: Double
    let close: Double
    let high: Double
    let low: Double
    let open: Double
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let data: [Level]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "Data"
    }
}

func fetchData(completion: @escaping (Response?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&limit=60&aggregate=3&e=CCCAGG")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { 
            completion(nil, MyError.FoundNil("data"))
        }

        do {
            if let marketData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                completion(marketData, nil)
            } else {
                completion(nil, MyError.DecodingData(data)) // work on this duplicated call
            }
        } catch {
            completion(nil, MyError.DecodingData(data)) // work on this duplicated call
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}

fetchData() { items, error in
    if let error == error {
        switch(error) {
            case .foundNil(let whatsNil):
                print("Something is nil: \(whatsNil)")
            case .decodingData(let data):
                print("Error decoding: \(data)")
        }
    } else {
        if let items = items {
            print(items.data[0].open)
            print(items.data[1].open)
            print("Average=", (items.data[0].open + items.data[1].open) / 2)

            print(items)
        } else {
            print("No items to show!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will keep this method in a Playground for reference, it works perfectly